# Foreign key does not exist error? Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm creating a database and making some tables.

I have a table 'written_by' which references table 'author' and 'book'
the creating code is as below.

```
CREATE TABLE WRITTEN_BY (
  NAME VARCHAR2(20),
  ADDRESS VARCHAR2(30),
  ISBN VARCHAR2(30),
  CONSTRAINT WB_FK FOREIGN KEY(NAME)
  REFERENCES AUTHOR(NAME),
  CONSTRAINT WB_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(ADDRESS)
  REFERENCES AUTHOR(ADDRESS),
  CONSTRAINT WB_FK3 FOREIGN KEY(ISBN)
  REFERENCES BOOK(ISBN)
);
```

When the code is executed, the script returns 'no primary key existing', but as searched by

```
SELECT cols.table_name, cols.column_name, cols.position, cons.status, cons.owner
FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
WHERE cons.constraint_type = 'P'
AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
AND cons.owner = cols.owner
ORDER BY cols.table_name, cols.position;
```

There are primary key 'name', 'address', and 'ISBN'.

*edit
Here's the 'author' table creating code.

```
CREATE TABLE AUTHOR (
  NAME VARCHAR2(20),
  ADDRESS VARCHAR2(30),
  URL VARCHAR2(100),
  CONSTRAINT A_PK PRIMARY KEY(NAME, ADDRESS)
);
```

Comment: There cannot be primary keys of both `NAME` and `ADDRESS` on the same table (`AUTHOR`) as you can only have a single primary key (unless you have a composite primary key but then you can't refer to the columns individually).

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with either: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the `AUTHOR` and `BOOK` tables; or the output from your data dictionary query (filtered to the relevant columns). Also, make sure you have checked that the tables are in the same schema and you may want to check unique constraints too.

Comment: I think the problem is that I referenced each primary keys individually. Added the 'book' table creating code, It worked well and all keys are unique, so maybe you could help me with refering the composite primary key, and problem will be solved?

Comment: As an aside, what happens when the author moves to a new address? With the current table structure, you would need to change all the child tables when the primary key is modified in the parent. It might be better to have a separate `IDENTITY` column as the primary key (which can then be used by the child tables) and then have a `UNIQUE` constraint on name and address.

Comment: What do you want to happen when no address is given, or no name? Both can be null in your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the composite key:

```sql
CREATE TABLE WRITTEN_BY (
  NAME VARCHAR2(20),
  ADDRESS VARCHAR2(30),
  ISBN VARCHAR2(30),
  CONSTRAINT WB_FK FOREIGN KEY(NAME, ADDRESS)
  REFERENCES AUTHOR(NAME, ADDRESS),
  CONSTRAINT WB_FK3 FOREIGN KEY(ISBN)
  REFERENCES BOOK(ISBN)
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=91ac2ea12e2cafdba6724e934e01c8d1)*